# Chord Chart - Skip to key with a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chord chart app that basically can transpose a chord chart up and down throughout the keys, but now I would like to expand that app and allow someone to pick a key and automatically go to that key upon a click event using a function in javascript or jquery. Can someone help me figure this out? The logic seems simple enough, but I'm just not sure how to implement it. Here are my current functions that allow the user to transpose up and down...

```
var match;
var chords = ['C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A','A#','B','C','Db','D','Eb','E','F','Gb','G','Ab','A','Bb','B','C'];
var chords2 = ['C','Db','D','Eb','E','F','Gb','G','Ab','A','Bb','B','C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A','A#','C'];
var chordRegex = /(?:C#|D#|F#|G#|A#|Db|Eb|Gb|Ab|Bb|C|D|E|F|G|A|B)/g;

function transposeUp(x) {   
  $('.chord'+x).each(function(){ ///// initializes variables /////  
  var currentChord = $(this).text(); // gatheres each object 
  var output = "";      
  var parts = currentChord.split(chordRegex);       
  var index = 0;        
  /////////////////////////////////         
  while (match = chordRegex.exec(currentChord)){            
    var chordIndex = chords2.indexOf(match[0]);             
    output += parts[index++] + chords[chordIndex+1]; 
  }         
  output += parts[index];       
  $(this).text(output);     
  }); 
}
```

---

```
function transposeDown(x){
    $('.chord'+x).each(function(){
    var currentChord = $(this).text(); // gatheres each object
    var output = "";
    var parts = currentChord.split(chordRegex);
    var index = 0;
    while (match = chordRegex.exec(currentChord)){
        var chordIndex = chords2.indexOf(match[0],1);
        //var chordIndex = $.inArray(match[0], chords, -1);
        output += parts[index++] + chords2[chordIndex-1];
    }
    output += parts[index];
    $(this).text(output);
});
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Answer will be accepted! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you want? a function that will create a click event?

```
$('[class^="chord"]').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text() + ' clicked');
});
```

*Based on your comment:* Here is some pseudo-code to get you going in the right direction:

- also store a transposed version of each chords array
- when a note is clicked, find its element in the original chords array (using `$(this).text()` above to match the note name)
- when a match is found, you can find its transposed version using the same array index

Comment: No, but thank you for your fast response. I have 12 chord choices... C,Db,D,Eb,E,F,F#,G,Ab,A,Bb,&B Upon clicking one of these I would like to jump the the trasposed key. If I am in 'C' and I click G, I need to move 7 steps up or if Ab I need to move 4 steps down and every chord in the chart needs to do so. Does this help?